# Menu with multiple options java

Tags: java, list, menu

I'm trying to create a program that will allow a user to select items from a menu and calculate the total at the end. I don't have to use a running total but this is the best option I saw for doing it with what I know.
When I run this code I receive the error

```
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M Main
Would you like (1.) Spaghetti, (2.) Hotdog, (3.) Cookie, (4.) Chicken Nuggets? Please enter a number value. Enter 0 to complete your order.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

and don't quite understand why. Any help on cleaning my code or explaining this error would be much appreciated.

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
            double Spaghetti = 1.03;
             double hotdog = 3.09;
              double Cookie = .59;
               double ChickenNuggets = 54.36;
               double total = 0.0;
               
               System.out.println("Would you like (1.) Spaghetti, (2.) Hotdog, (3.) Cookie, (4.) Chicken Nuggets? Please enter a number value. Enter 0 to complete your order.");
               double option = input.nextDouble();
               
               while (option != 0){
                   option =+ total;
               }
               if(option == 1){
                   Spaghetti += total;
               }
                if(option == 2){
                   hotdog += total;
               }
                if(option == 3){
                   Cookie += total;
               }
                if(option == 4){
                   ChickenNuggets += total;
               }
                 System.out.println("Your total is " + total);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is causing your error, but you're adding `total` to your food item prices, not the other way around. For example, `option` 1 should be `total += Spaghetti`. You should also rethink your entire program flow. Your `while` loop isn't actually a loop (there is nothing within that code block that would cause it to repeat). Several other issues here. I recommend using you debugger to step through your code line by line to see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of the comment, you are not adding into the total correctly.
The correct syntax is:

```
total += Cookie;
```

or

```
total = total + Cookie;
```

Also since you mentioned that the code is supposed to allow multiple selections you must implement code to allow more than one selection.  There are a few ways to do this:

A nice structure to use would be the structure similar to the one recommended for getopt_long() in C but for Java obviously. Can read the man page here https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long

```
double option;
while(true)
{
    option = input.nextDouble();      
  
    if(option == 0) //If option is 0 then you quit asking the user
    {
        break; //session terminated
    }

    switch (option) {
        case 1.0: 
            total += spaghetti;
            break;
    
        case 2.0:
            total = total + hotdog;
            break;
        case 3.0:
            total += Cookie;
            break;
        case 4.0:
            total  = total + ChickenNuggets;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input, try again");    
            break;
    }

}
```

Another good solution to this problem, if you don't want to use the switch statement, is the loop-and-a-half.
https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Basic-JavaScript-and-Graphics/loop-and-a-half.html

The structure goes like this:

```
double option;
while(true)
{
    option = input.nextDouble();

    if(option == 1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(option == 2)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    // Add rest of options
    else if(option == 0) //If user types a 0 we quit
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
    }
}
```

Feel free to change and manipulate the code to suit your needs.  This is merely a suggested way to perform the function and is best suited to be treated as a skeleton.

Comment: Thank you both so much! Most of my issue was with the ide I was using. For some reason, it didn't throw that error when I ran it through a different one. This still helped immensely with my code though. I ended up reading on the loop-and- a-half and using that. Thank you both again!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!  A nice java IDE would be IntelliJ IDEA which is free for students I believe.